Configuring MAMP for SSL - Free edition
I'm trying to configure MAMP 4.5 for SSL.
The goal is to build a self-hosting serveur with a SSL certificate delivered by GeoTrust.
The provider send me to files (.key and .cer).
I try to tell apache web server to use these files.
For that I modified 2 files :
/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
and     /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
In the httpd.conf file,
I remove the # in front of httpd-ssl.conf.
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

I uncomment IfDefine SSL to make sure LoadModule is executed
<IfDefine SSL>
        LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfDefine>

Then, in the httpd-ssl.conf file,
I replace  with <VirtualHost *:443>.
Then I replace
 DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/htdocs"
    ServerName www.example.com:443
    ServerAdmin you@example.com
    ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/error_log"
    TransferLog "/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/access_log"

With
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/access_log"

I customize the path of the certificat and the path of the key
SSLCertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/ssl/server.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/ssl/server.key

I comment out IfDefine SSL and closing tag to enable Listen 443
I save and close the two file and try to Start my MAMP server.
But MAMP never start ! I try to find an error on the log file. But no error appear ! I'm really disappointed.
I hove you could help me.
Best regards.

Please do not post duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78635075/mamp-5-06-windows-configuring-httpd-ssl-conf
